# Company name not in a single line

Tags: titles

I am trying to get the output of this Latex code but, my company name is not coming in a single line if I use the `\Huge` relative font size.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{pagecolor,lipsum}

\begin{document}    

\title{%
 \Huge BANGALORE MATHEMATICAL INSTITUTE \\
  \large Coaching for IIT-JEE/NEET/KVPY/OLYMPIADS}

\author{Director: G Ekaveera Kumar}

\maketitle
\pagecolor{cyan!30!yellow}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to make the string `BANGALORE MATHEMATICAL INSTITUTE` fit on a single line, you must either use a relative font size *smaller* than `\Huge` (`\huge` is ok) or increase the width of the text block. Which option do you prefer?

Comment: i  tried smaller than \Huge but not satisfied with it

Comment: `14pt` isn't recognized either by the `article` document class; it recognizes only `10pt` (the default), `11pt`, and `12pt` as fontsize-related options.

Comment: yes i understood

Comment: thanks i fixed it using class extreport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `14pt` is the basic document font size, then the string "Bangalore Mathematical Institute" simply cannot fit on a single line if the `\Huge` relative font size is in force. The largest permissible relative font size is `\huge`, as the following example demonstrates. Note that I also changed the all-caps title to small-caps, as I believe that all-caps text is quite unreadable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\begin{document}    
\title{%
   \huge
   \makebox[0pt]{\textsc{Bangalore Mathematical Institute}}\\[4ex]
   \Large 
   Coaching for IIT-JEE/NEET/KVPY/\textsc{Olympiads}}
\author{Director: G Ekaveera Kumar}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent awesome. But is pagecolor supported here?

Comment: FYI Page color is compatible. thank you